# Expo-AV - When our app gets minimised/closed it pauses the users background music e.g. spotify

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video, expo, expo-av

We've got a really strange issue where a muted video is playing on our app, but when you minimise the app, if the user has background music playing on something like Spotify or Apple music, it pauses their music?

Our component is effectively this...

```js
import { Video } from 'expo-av'

const intro = require('@/assets/videos/welcome_intro.mp4')

export const Background = () => {
  return <Video
    style={{ position: 'absolute', width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
    source={ intro }
    resizeMode="cover"
    isLooping={ true }
    isMuted={ true }
    shouldPlay={ true }
/>
}
```

Our .mp4 has no audio channel in it either so shouldn't get picked up.

However the moment we delete this `Video` component the app works as expected.

The desired outcome is........

> Play the muted video in the background, without affecting the users music/audio etc in any scenario. The video should be treated like it has no audio.

Ideas?

Comment: Did you fix this problem? I'm having the same problem and have been trying to fix it for days now

Comment: Nothing yet? What the heck?